# How to get an Android app's notification badge?

Tags: android

When an Android application pushes a notification, it most often uses a custom badge (not its usual icon) that's then masked by the system.

Is it possible to extract that badge?

Answer (score 1):

Never tested but seems to be possible.

First you need to create a service which extend [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService).

Inside the onNotificationPosted method you will receive a [StatusBarNotification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification) object every time a notification is posted on the device. You can use the getNotification method on it to get a [Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification) object, then inside they are a bundle called "extra" which contains some properties [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#extras) the one you are insterested in, is probably "[largeIcon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#largeIcon)" you can get it as demontrated in [this example](http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-read-notification-title-text-and-package-name-in-android/23198/) (here you get the title but you will need to change it to get the bitmap).

You can see [here](https://github.com/Chagall/notification-listener-service-example) a github project showing an example of NotificationListenerService

### Edit

This is a solution for any application and real time, if you just want to get an icon from a specific application, use some tools such as Apk-tool to uncompile it, and search inside its ressources the drawable (image) you are interested in.